# Infinite horizontal scroll has white space at end of div

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

I am trying to create an animation where the div containing all of the cards slides from right to left, which I have achieved.

The problem is there is a huge white gap in between the end of the div and when it resets, I managed to fix this by specifying that at `100%` the div should have translated `-1110px` however this causes a stutter as the carousel resets.

is there anyway I can have the animation reset back at 0% without causing a stuttering effect? Code is below

```
<div className="scroll-container" id="reset">
  <div className="scroll">
    <Card industry="Industry" description="Description" />
    <Card industry="Industry" description="Description" />
    <Card industry="Industry" description="Description" />
    <Card industry="Industry" description="Description" />
    <Card industry="Industry" description="Description" />
    <Card industry="Industry" description="Description" />
    <Card industry="Industry" description="Description" />
    <Card industry="Industry" description="Description" />
    <Card industry="Industry" description="Description" />
    <Card industry="Industry" description="Description" />
    <Card industry="Industry" description="Description" />
    <Card industry="Industry" description="Description" />
    <Card industry="Industry" description="Description" />
  </div>
  <div className="scroll">
    <Card industry="Industry" description="Description" />
    <Card industry="Industry" description="Description" />
    <Card industry="Industry" description="Description" />
    <Card industry="Industry" description="Description" />
    <Card industry="Industry" description="Description" />
    <Card industry="Industry" description="Description" />
    <Card industry="Industry" description="Description" />
    <Card industry="Industry" description="Description" />
    <Card industry="Industry" description="Description" />
    <Card industry="Industry" description="Description" />
    <Card industry="Industry" description="Description" />
    <Card industry="Industry" description="Description" />
    <Card industry="Industry" description="Description" />
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.scroll-container {
  position: relative;
  animation: scroll 5s linear infinite;
}
.scroll {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
  transform: translateX(82px);
}
@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-1110px);
  }
}
```

[image: image of the whitespace after div]

Comment: What white gap are you talking about? Please take a screenshot.

Comment: I have added a screenshot that contains the whitespace after the div when the animation 100% is set to `transform: translateX(-100%)`

Answer (score 0):

Add 50% in the animation as below :

```
    @keyframes scroll {
      0% {
        transform: translateX(0%);
      }
      50% {
        transform: translateX(-1110px);
      }
      100% {
        transform: translateX(0%);
      }
    }
```

And change the animation duration from 5s to 10s so that it will be in same delay as earlier.

Comment: All this does is cause the div to change direction at 50%

Comment: Bro use inspect element in your browser to debug this error.

Comment: I've had a look at inspect element and honestly I'm not sure where to begin